# Inject content script into iFrame across domains (but with optional permissions)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm aware that you are able to load external domains in iFrames in Chrome Extensions by specifying their permissions in the manifest, and using content_scripts with all_frames to inject your own code.

However, I am now using optional_permissions to avoid user prompts on install, and opted to instead prompt when the user actual needs said permission. The idea is to load a content script inside an iFrame of specific pages. What I did before was run the content script on all pages, but use a #hash to specify when to run frame specific code.

Now that I only use optional_permissions, how do I go about actually getting the script to run inside the iFrame?

Basically I want something like this in my main window.

```
on userAction {
    loadFrame(externalURL); // This I can do just fine.
    loadContentScriptinFrame(); // How do I do this?
}
```

Or is there some manifest trickery that works with a combination of `content_scripts`, `optional_permissions`, `all_frames`, and `if(frame){doStuff()}` ?

Comment: You can use content script declaring with optional permissions. Make sure that the optional permissions are only declared in "optional_permissions", and not in "permissions" or in "content_scripts[*].matches". Use the "chrome.declarativeContent.RequestContentScript" action to insert a content script in the page. See the reference for more details about the API: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent

Comment: @gui47 In theory, that would be the preferred solution. In practice, that method is not yet usable with optional permissions, see https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=429944.

Comment: I've marked the question as a duplicate because of the overlap of topic. Currently you cannot inject in a specific frame (only all frames), but [there is work in progress](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=63979).

Comment: For future reference, both issues are now fixed. Good to know that @RobW is a Chromium author 